# Is there a required field for Rally SDK 2 tagpicker? Object has no method 'getContextPath'

Tags: javascript, rally

In Rally SDK 2, I made a tag picker and then added it to a container.  It renders ok, but when the user hits the drop-down arrow, the console reports an error (Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getContextPath') and the tag picker doesn't let the user pick tags (every other time, though, they are listed).

```
        this.tag_picker = Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.TagPicker', {
            width: 275,
            fieldLabel: "Tags: ",
            allowBlank: true,
            minHeight: 100,
            autoExpand: true
        });
        this.down('#big_box').add( this.tag_picker );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug when querying for preference keys to determine if a tooltip should be shown and it tries to build the request URL with Rally.getContextPath().  As a workaround, you can set toolTipPreferenceKey to undefined (toolTipPreferenceKey: undefined) to avoid seeing this error.